# Django AttributeError at /customer/2/ 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django

Hi I am trying to resolve my error issues that I am trying to filter in my customer template. In my views if I place `entry_objects= Entry.objects.all()`. It is fine, but I want to be able to filter by customer. My query set worked but I can't do reverse bottom to up. :(

**Models.py**:

```
    class customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null = True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class UserTopic(models.Model):
    #category for user to chose
    #User interest
    text = models.CharField(max_length=120, null =True) #we want to display characters with max 250
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True ) #allows realtime accuracy upon upload
    #string representation of model
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
    class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name
    #entry model

class Entry(models.Model):
    cust_name = models.ForeignKey(customer, null= True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    tags = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(UserTopic, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:10]+"..."
# ...
on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
```

**Views.py**:

```
def customer_page(request, pk_test):
    customer_objects = customer.objects.get(id=pk_test),
    entry_objects = customer.entry_set.all()

    #entry = Entry.objects.all()
    context = {
        'entry_objects': entry_objects,
        'customer_objects': customer_objects,
    }   
    return render(request, 'user_log/customer.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `related_name` field on your Foreign Key so that other model can refer this model back using `realated_name` field.

```py
class Entry(models.Model):
    cust_name = models.ForeignKey(customer, null= True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="entries")
```

Use your customer object (retrieved using pk) to reach all his entries

```py
customer_objects = customer.objects.get(id=pk_test),
entry_objects = customer_objects.entries.all()
```

Note: I believe `customer_objects` is retrieved correctly using `pk`. Use sigular name `customer_object` not `customer_objects` .

Comment: It returns a "AttributeError at /customer/1/ 'tuple' object has no attribute 'entry_set'". When I access the customers id such as customer/1/. Is this a model relationship error on my end?

Comment: Modified the `Entry` model's `cust_name` field. Check now, this way customer object will refer fetch all entry pointing to that particular customer.
Code is correct .but make sure `customer_objects` is actually a customer object and not a tuple. (Try printing it's class using `type(customer_objects)` and `print(customer_objects)`)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have been researching answers through the website and online and could not find anything! I appreciate your help! This makes sense to me and learned from this!